# Annotations won't load on map

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mapkit, cloudkit

I have been trying to get directions to annotations all over my map for some time. I have recently found out how to do that but now not all my annotations will show up on the map, only one does. I am using a public database in `Cloudkit` to store all my users information. Ever since I made the variable `annotation = MKPointAnnotation()` available for the whole view controller not all my annotations have been showing on the map.

This is how I get directions:

```
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

@IBAction func getDirections(_ sender: Any) {
    let view = annotation.coordinate        
    print("Annotation: \(String(describing: view ))")
    let currentLocMapItem = MKMapItem.forCurrentLocation()
    let selectedPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: view, addressDictionary: nil)
    let selectedMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: selectedPlacemark)
    let mapItems = [selectedMapItem, currentLocMapItem]
    let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]
    MKMapItem.openMaps(with: mapItems, launchOptions:launchOptions)
}
```

This is how I show my annotations:

```
func fetch() {
    let truePredicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let eventQuery = CKQuery(recordType: "User", predicate: truePredicate)
    let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: eventQuery)
    queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record : CKRecord!) in

        self.truck.append(record)

        self.annotation.title = record?["username"] as? String
        self.annotation.subtitle = record?["hours"] as? String
        if let location = record?["location"] as? CLLocation {
            self.annotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
        }

        print("recordFetchedBlock: \(record)")

        self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.annotation)
    }

    queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor, error) in

        print("queryCompletionBlock: \(self.truck)")
    }

    database.add(queryOperation)
}
```

I'm now getting this error:

```
This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.
```

Comment: The error shows that you are doing UI changes in Background thread, Because of that you are facing this error log. Update your code and write all UI changes in main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Surjeet said, write all UI changes in main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.annotation)
}
```

Comment: Thank You! I was stressing about the main thread, I was putting the dispatchQueue in the wrong places. I'm still confused on how the map only shows one annotation when I make "let annotation = mkpointannotation()" available for the whole controller.